# Lodash - method which return non-share elements from two arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

Helo guys, could you help with:

I need a method to lodash which return:

```
_.method( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3] ) => [4,5,6,7]
```

In other words method which return non-share elements.

Best regards
Greg.

Comment: [`_.difference(array, [values])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#difference).

> Creates an array of `array` values not included in the other given arrays using [`SameValueZero`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) for equality comparisons. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array.

```js
var result = _.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, indeed, on numbers it is working. But on objects, I get full copy of first table:/ Inside of function: 

albumNotPhotos = _.difference(this.albumNotPhotos, this.albumPhotos);

And I get copy of first argument:/. I'v checked it on debugger. I need more debugging...

Answer (score 0):

I found:

For Objects it should be:

```
albumNotPhotos = _.differenceWith(this.albumNotPhotos, this.albumPhotos, _.isEqual);
```

Thanks and regards!@